# React : Empty values on PUT for axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list that I get from an **API** using **axios**.
Every element is a modifiable input, with it own **update** button.

After changing the data of an input, and while performing PUT request, `console.log(test);` returns empty values.

I checked `console.log(newList);` which is the array of the list, and the changing data are indeed happening in the list, but it seems they can't be sent to the server.

*Note : The API is just for testing, the PUT method may not work, but atleast the values in the console should be sent.*

*Note2 : I don't know how to place the `id` of an item of the list in the url so you may encounter an error.* / You can try with 1,2 or 3 instead for testing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-snowflake-dw1xr?file=/src/App.js:1809-1834

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default () => {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = React.useState("");
  const [city, setCity] = React.useState("");

  // Getting initial list from API
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://6092374385ff5100172122c8.mockapi.io/api/test/users")
      .then((response) => {
        setList(response.data);
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  // onUpdate to update the data in the API
  const onUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const test = {
      name: name,
      description: description,
      city: city
    };

    console.log(test);

    // axios request PUT data on API
    axios
      .put(
        "https://6092374385ff5100172122c8.mockapi.io/api/test/users" + id,
        test
      )
      .then((res) => {
        alert("success");
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    // axios request GET to get the new modified list from the database, after the update
    axios
      .get("https://6092374385ff5100172122c8.mockapi.io/api/test/users")
      .then((res) => {
        alert("success");
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  // Handler for changing values of each input
  function handleChangeUpdate(id, event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const newList = list.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const updatedItem = {
          ...item,
          [name]: value
        };

        return updatedItem;
      }
      return item;
    });
    setList(newList);
    console.log(newList);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <input
                className="form-control"
                name="name"
                onChange={(event) => handleChangeUpdate(item.id, event)}
                defaultValue={item.name}
              ></input>

              <input
                className="form-control"
                name="description"
                onChange={(event) => handleChangeUpdate(item.id, event)}
                defaultValue={item.description}
              ></input>

              <input
                className="form-control"
                name="city"
                onChange={(event) => handleChangeUpdate(item.id, event)}
                defaultValue={item.city}
              ></input>

              <button onClick={onUpdate}>Update</button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes, ```newList``` is indeed changing when onChange. However, ```const test``` is always empty because you doesn't ```setName()```, ```setDescription()```, ```setCity()``` which you should have to.

Comment: @GanHongJian What do you mean ? They are already set in hooks, no ?

Comment: Yes, it is in hooks, but you are just reading ```name``` and not writing value with ```setName``` first. Thats why you always have empty value (default value of "").

Comment: @Gan Hong Jian I see. Do you mind showing me how to set value for `setName` etc .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you never set the values of the props. That is why they never change from their initial values. You just update the `list` prop in *handleChangeUpdate*. There are two steps you need to take with the existing file structure:

1. Make *handleChangeUpdate* be able to differentiate between different props (*city*, *description*, etc.). For example, by passing the prop's name.
2. Update the prop's value in the *handleChangeUpdate*.

To realize the first step, you can change the *input* tag like the following:

```html
{/* attention to the first argument of handleChangeUpdate */}
<input
    className="form-control"
    name="name"
    onChange={(event) => handleChangeUpdate("name", item.id, event)}
    defaultValue={item.name}
></input>
```

Then, you need to adjust the *handleChangeUpdate*:

```js
if (name === "name") {
    setName(value);
} else if (name === "description") {
    setDescription(value);
} else if (name === "city") {
    setCity(value);
}
```

By the way, *list* is not a good name for a variable.

#### Alternatively

Without creating new parameters, you can also use only the *event* to set the props

```js
  // Handler for changing values of each input
  function handleChangeUpdate(id, event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const newList = list.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const updatedItem = {
          ...item,
          [name]: value
        };

        return updatedItem;
      }
      return item;
    });
    setList(newList);
    console.log(newList);

    if (name === "name") {
      setName(value);
    } else if (name === "description") {
      setDescription(value);
    } else if (name === "city") {
      setCity(value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood what you meant, I did exatcly what you suggested, but it didn't work for some reason. Replaced both in input and handleChangeUpdate

Comment: Don't do _exactly_ what I suggested. You should update *all* 3 inputs with the new _handleChangeUpdate_. Secondly, you should only insert the if-else-statements to the bottom of _handleChangeUpdate_ without needing to change the rest.

Comment: Well this is what I did. I changed it for all inputs and put the if statement at the bottom of the update function. You can directly check my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-snowflake-dw1xr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Updated the answer. in that case, you only need to insert the if-elses without changing the rest.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work unfortunately. You can try it directly on the codesandbox I provided.

Comment: check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-rubin-rcxoh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You are right it's working. But the problem here is that when the other values are not changed, the values that are send to the server are empty. Making them null on the database.

Comment: Yeah, because you need to set them as well, when you receive those values. then you'll be fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. What do you mean by set them ? The entire list is fetched from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 3 errors in the `onUpdate` function.

1. You are not passing the `id` of the item from the `onClick` event
2. Your `put` method should be change
3. You should not perform `get` request as soon as after the `put` request, because sometimes the backend will not updated yet.

You can update your code as below,

1.Pass the `id` of the item when the button is clicked.

```
<button onClick={onUpdate(item.id)}>Update</button>
```

2. Modify the `put` method, passing the `id`

```
axios
      .put(
        `https://6092374385ff5100172122c8.mockapi.io/api/test/users/${e}`,
        test
      ).then((res) => {
        alert("success");
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

3.Perform the `get` request after the response of the `put` request

```
  const onUpdate = (e) => {

    const test = {
      name: name,
      description: description,
      city: city
    };

    console.log(test);

    // axios request PUT data on API
    axios
      .put(
        `https://6092374385ff5100172122c8.mockapi.io/api/test/users/${e}`,
        test
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);

        // axios request GET to get the new modified list from the database, after the update
        axios
          .get("https://6092374385ff5100172122c8.mockapi.io/api/test/users")
          .then((res) => {
             alert("success");
            console.log(res);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all. You can test directly on codesandbox I provided.